# Boolean operators within a string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to add a bracket to operands of `OR` operator. For example, if I have statement as below,

```
C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5
```

I would like to format it as below

```
(C>O AND C>4) OR (C>0 AND C>5)
```

I wrote a simple code to do this as below. However, if the string has more than one `OR` statements the code doesn't work properly. I was told that the regular expression could accomplish this. But I have very minimum knowledge in regular expression.

```
string mystring = "C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5";
int indexFound = mystring.IndexOf("OR");
string left = mystring.Substring(0, indexFound - 1);
string right = mystring.Substring(indexFound + 2, mystring.Length - (indexFound + 2));
string output = "(" + left + ")" + "OR" + "(" + right + ")";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Frankly I'd be looking at this using a proper expression parser to build a tree, then write the normalized tree - I'm thinking "shunting yard"

Comment: This would probably call for a lexical tokenizer with understanding of operator priority... It's not a simple task.

Comment: What behavior do you expect if string has several OR statements, e.g. `C>9 OR C>O OR C>0 AND C>5`? It could be `(C>9 OR C>O) OR (C>0 AND C>5)` or `(C>9) OR (C>O OR C>0 AND C>5)`, or even `((C>9) OR (C>O)) OR (C>0 AND C>5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way via regular expressions:

```
static string AddBracketsToOr(string input)
{            
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<left>.+[AND|OR].+) OR (?<right>.+[AND|OR].+)");
    Match match = regex.Match(input);

    if (match == null)
        throw new Exception("Wrong input format");

    return String.Format("({0}) OR ({1})", 
                         match.Groups["left"], match.Groups["right"]);
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = AddBracketsToOr("C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5");
```

UPDATE:
Works with

```
"C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5" // (C>O AND C>4) OR (C>0 AND C>5)
"C>9 OR C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5" // (C>9 OR C>O AND C>4) OR (C>0 AND C>5)
"C>9 OR C>O OR C>0 AND C>5" // (C>9 OR C>O) OR (C>0 AND C>5)
```

Comment: What about `C>9 OR C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5` ?

Comment: This is not the case of question, but you can change regex like this `(?<left>.+AND.+) OR (?<right>.+AND.+)` to be sure that `AND` exists in both parts

Comment: If I downvoted you, I would cancel it, but this doesn't change the fact that you can't make an expression evaluator(beautifier) with just regex. What if the expression would be more complex(`(`s etc.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see at the beginning, that question was about several OR statements in one string. I agree with you, that expression tree building is not case for regex.

Comment: It's interesting what @balan really expects to see :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, your answer works well for the sample input in the question. However, how do I modify it to produce (C>9 OR (C>O AND C>4)) OR (C>0 AND C>5) for input C>9 OR C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5? Every AND statement should be in the bracket if one or more OR statement exist. I am sorry if my question is not complete.

Comment: @balan what about several consequential ANDs `C>9 OR C>O AND C<2 AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5`?

Comment: @lazyberezosky, I believe the order of ANDs in the logical operation is irrelevant. However it makes significant different when the order of ORs are not correct. Adding brackets as shown above would allow me to perform the logical operation in correct order.

Comment: @balan and what about ORs order? `C>9 OR C>O OR (C>1 AND C<2 AND C>4) OR (C>0 AND C>5) OR C<5` which rule do you apply for wrapping ORs in brackets?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I think ORs order is matter ONLY when there is AND statement. In your example, C>9 OR C>O OR (C>1 AND C<2 AND C>4) OR (C>0 AND C>5) OR C<5 - the AND operation will get performed first because it is inside the bracket. So the order of ORs not important here. When we have combination of ANDs and ORs then the ANDs should be in bracket so that it get performed first before the ORs.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using any regular expressions in your code at the moment.

The `.Substring()` method finds the first `OR` inside `mystring` and splits it into `left` and `right` sub-strings. Hence, only the first `OR` can be handled the way you describe.

You will have to create a loop over `mystring` until no occurence of `OR` can be found anymore.

**Sample code**

```
string mystring = "C>O AND C>4 OR C>0 AND C>5";
string output = "";

int indexFound = mystring.IndexOf("OR");

// indexOf returns -1 if the string cannot be found.
// We quit our loop once -1 is returned.
while (indexFound > -1)
{
    // Compute the "left" side of our current mystring.
    string left = mystring.Substring(0, indexFound - 1);

    // And then append it to our final output variable.
    output += "(" + left + ")" + "OR";

    // Instead of directly adding the "right" side, we
    // "shorten" mystring to only contain the right side.
    // This effectively "skips" over the "left" and "OR"
    // and will allow us to process the remaining "OR"s.
    mystring = mystring.Substring(indexFound + 2)

    // Finally, we update indexFound to check if there
    // are any more "OR"s inside our mystring.
    indexFound = mystring.IndexOf("OR");
}

// Before returning, we add the remaining mystring to
// our output.  You have to decide whether you want
// to add the parentheses here.
output += "(" + mystring + ")";
```

Hope that helps.